# How to print surrogate chars as ints in Java

Tags: java, unicode, surrogate-pairs

I have this:

```
char c = "\ud804\udef4".charAt(0);
char d = "\ud804\udef4".charAt(1);
```

How will I print `c` and `d` as hex Strings ?

I want `d804` for `c` and `def4` for `d`.

Comment: What result do you want? Do you want `d804` for `c` and `def4` for `d`?

Comment: @Sweeper correct.

Comment: "surrogate chars as ints", meaning their code points? cause your title does not match the comment you left.

Comment: You can use a format specifier as well `printf("%x", (int) c)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the char is a surrogate pair or not. If you have a `char`, you can convert it to a hex string by [`Integer.toHexString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)), since `char`s can be implicitly converted to `int`.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(c));
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(d));
```

Comment: Is there a better way that does not rely on char to int implicitly conversion ?

Comment: Are you implying that "relying on char to int implicit conversion" is somehow "worse" than not doing so. If you are, why? If you are not, what constitutes a "better" way? @AnkurAgarwal

Comment: @AnkurAgarwal not really, because just about *any* arithmetic you try to perform on the `char` (for instance, if you try to create a hex string manually using bit shifts and what-not) is going to implicitly convert the `char` anyway, typically to `int`. So, why wouldn't you want to just let Java do the work for you?